# IOS5 How can I retain objects in an array

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller

Please Help, what do I need to do to retain the objects in my array 'resultArray'? I used "retain" but it did not help. The array has objects when accessed in 'doMyAction', then I do "performSegueWithIdentifier" which connects to try2FlipsideViewController where I try to access the "setText" method defined in the first controller and the array is now with no objects.

Actually my goal is to display in the Flip contoler some error message determined in the Main controller. I also tried to push the string as "homeController.resultDisplay.text = self.myTextField.text;" but it compiles and nothing happens.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated, thank you.

try2MainViewController.m

```
#import "try2MainViewController.h"
#import "try2Model.h"
@interface try2MainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) try2Model * brain;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * resultArray;
@end

@implementation try2MainViewController
@synthesize myTextField;
@synthesize brain = _brain;
@synthesize resultArray;  

- (IBAction)doMyAction:(id)sender {

resultArray = [self.brain someMethod];

NSString * resultCode = (NSString *)[resultArray objectAtIndex:0];


if ([resultCode isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

    NSNumberFormatter * myFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [myFormat setPositiveFormat:@"0.##"];
    NSNumber * testNo = (NSNumber *)[resultArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString * anca = [myFormat stringFromNumber:testNo];
    self.myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<< result %@%%",anca]; 

} 

NSString * r = (NSString *)[resultArray objectAtIndex:1];//*&* test

[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showAlternate" 
                          sender: self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {

        try2FlipsideViewController * homeController = (try2FlipsideViewController  *)[segue destinationViewController];

    homeController.resultDisplay.text = self.myTextField.text;


    [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}

- (NSString *) setText {
   NSString * r = (NSString *)[resultArray objectAtIndex:1];//*&* test
   return r;
}
```

try2FlipsideViewController.m

```
#import "try2FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "try2MainViewController.h"

@interface try2FlipsideViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) try2MainViewController * getMain;

@end
@implementation try2FlipsideViewController
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize resultDisplay = _resultDisplay;
@synthesize getMain = _getMain;

-(try2MainViewController *)getMain
{
    if (!_getMain) {
        _getMain = [[try2MainViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return _getMain;
 }


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     r = [self.getMain setText];
     self.resultDisplay.text = r
}
```

Comment: In your `doMyAction` method, instead of `resultArray = ...` have you tried using `self.resultArray = ...`? Because otherwise you bypass the setter which might cause your problem.

Comment: Thanks, adding 'self.' to 'resultArray' did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `try2FlipsideViewController` you call `getMain` which creates a brand new instance of the `try2MainViewController` class; one in which `doMyAction` has not been called and `resultArray` has not been set.

Perhaps you should add a `NSString` property to the `try2FlipsideViewController` called `resultDisplayText` and in the `prepareForSegue` method in the `try2MainViewController` set the property:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        try2FlipsideViewController * homeController = (try2FlipsideViewController  *)[segue destinationViewController];
        homeController.resultDisplayText = [self setText]; // <-- here it is
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

When `try2FlipsideViewController` loads:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.resultDisplay.text = self.resultDisplayText
}
```

Comment: Oh and the reason that `homeController.resultDisplay.text = self.myTextField.text;` didn't work is because when you called it in the prepareForSegue method, the thing that is `resultDisplay` (I'm guessing a `UILabel` ?) probably didn't exist because the view was not loaded yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanations. You solved my problem and I understand better how it works.